# Saltstack: can I use file.manage to source a file created by another salt state?

Tags: salt-stack

noob saltstack question

I have a file that is created in a salt state (a war file) and I want to copy that file to the server's deploy directory when it changes.  I was thinking `file.managed` would be the right approach, so something like:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app.war:
  file.managed:
    - source: /home/user/project/build/release/app.war
    - user: tomcat7
    - group: tomcat7
```

The file is built via a separate state, which seems to be running properly.

When salt exec's `state.highstate`, the output is
    "Unable to determine upstream hash of source file /home/user/project/build/release/app.war"

Is there a better way to do this?  Build a file in one state (so it is local) and then update a target when the built file changes?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change that to a `file.copy` instead, as `file.managed` is for fetching files over from the salt master or HTTP/FTP servers.

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app.war:
  file.copy:
    - source: /home/user/project/build/release/app.war
    - force: True
    - user: tomcat7
    - group: tomcat7
    - require:
      - cmd: the_build_state
```

As for linking it to the build, you need to use `require`, as in the modified state above, which assumes that your build state is defined like this:

```
the_build_state:
  - cmd.run:
    ...
```

Comment: Thx, Amr.  That works quite well.  I did add an `-unless cmp src dest` to prevent always doing the copy but otherwise good.